# Create bower component and inject into index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I'm creating my first bower component and im having some issues.

Hhere is my component - https://github.com/yuvalsaraf/bower-component and I've already registered it with bower with the name 'bower-component' (I'll delete it after I will create my first bower component successfully).

I'm having two problems -

1. Even though I specified the main files only to be  - one JS file, one CSS file, and one GIF file, it still downloads index.html to the user downloading the component.
2. The JS and the CSS files are not injected into my index.html file (on grunt bowerInstall command).
   I added a dependency to jQuery and it is injected fine.

Please check the repo and tell me what I'm doing wrong.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are tags in your GIT repository?

Comment: I see that you have implemented suggestion from my answer. If this not a problem, please accept my answer. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

`bower info bower-component`

returns "No versions available.". This is signal that you haven't use **git tags** in proper way.

You must create some tags, e.g

`git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "Release version 0.0.1"`

Then push it to remote repository (origin?)

`git push --tags`

To filter unnecessary files use **ignore** array

Comment: I added a tag as you suggested, still not behaving..help?

Comment: To filter unnecessary files use **ignore** array from `bower.json`